# Remove space between yAxis and data in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I would like to remove the space between y-axis and the chart  as shown below: 
[image]

Here is a fiddle used to create this chart : [jsFiddle for this chart](http://jsfiddle.net/basarat/pfkbX/)

Here is the code used to setup (same as jsFiddle):

```
$(function () {
   var chart;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    spacingLeft: 2,
                    spacingRight: 2
                },
                credits: { enabled: false },
                title: { text: '' },
                yAxis: {
                    title: '',
                    labels: {
                        style: {
                            fontSize:'9px'
                        }
                    }
                },
                xAxis: { labels: { enabled: false } }, //hide the x axis labels 

                series: [{
                    type: 'area',
                    name: 'speed',
                    showInLegend: false,
                    data: [
                        71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144, 176, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 129.2, 144, 176, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 129.2, 144, 176, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 129.2, 144, 176, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 129.2, 144, 176, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 129.2, 144, 176, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6,
                        71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144, 176, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 129.2, 144, 176, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 129.2, 144, 176, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 129.2, 144, 176, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 129.2, 144, 176, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 129.2, 144, 176, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6,
                        54.4]
                }],
                /* To make it pretty */
                plotOptions: {
                    area: {
                        animation: false,
                        lineWidth: 1,
                        marker: {
                            enabled: false,
                            states: {
                                hover: {
                                    enabled: true,
                                    radius: 5
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        shadow: false,
                        states: {
                            hover: {
                                lineWidth: 1
                            }
                        },
                        threshold: null
                    }
                }
            });
        });

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right way to do it is set the `offset` to `-15`.

```
yAxis: {
    offset: -15
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/pfkbX/2/)

**offset**:

`The distance in pixels from the plot area to the axis line. A positive offset moves the axis with it's line, labels and ticks away from the plot area. This is typically used when two or more axes are displayed on the same side of the plot. Defaults to 0.`

[reference](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#yAxis.offset)

Answer (score 2):

Consider using the following using your xAxis object:

```
        maxPadding:0,
        minPadding:0
```

Also make sure your labels closure doesn't include a 'step'

min and max are also a handy way to bind

Answer (score 1):

Fixed : http://jsfiddle.net/basarat/pfkbX/1/

Basically need to add yAxis.align = 'left'. Also move the labels up a bit (so they are on the line instead of under the line by setting the y=2 property) and also bring them into focus with x=0 property:

```
$(function () {
   var chart;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    spacingLeft: 2,
                    spacingRight: 2
                },
                credits: { enabled: false },
                title: { text: '' },
                yAxis: {
                    title: '',
                    labels: {
                        style: {
                            fontSize:'9px'
                        },
                      y:-2,
                      x:0,
                      align:'left'
                    }
                },
                xAxis: { labels: { enabled: false } }, //hide the x axis labels 

                series: [{
                    type: 'area',
                    name: 'speed',
                    showInLegend: false,
                    data: [
                        71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144, 176, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 129.2, 144, 176, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 129.2, 144, 176, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 129.2, 144, 176, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 129.2, 144, 176, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 129.2, 144, 176, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6,
                        71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144, 176, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 129.2, 144, 176, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 129.2, 144, 176, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 129.2, 144, 176, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 129.2, 144, 176, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 129.2, 144, 176, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6,
                        54.4]
                }],
                /* To make it pretty */
                plotOptions: {
                    area: {
                        animation: false,
                        lineWidth: 1,
                        marker: {
                            enabled: false,
                            states: {
                                hover: {
                                    enabled: true,
                                    radius: 5
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        shadow: false,
                        states: {
                            hover: {
                                lineWidth: 1
                            }
                        },
                        threshold: null
                    }
                }
            });
        });

});
```