# Highstock / Highchart - Trouble with range on multiple yAxis

Tags: highcharts

Do you see the range problem when I use multiple yAxis? How Can I solve this problem?

[image]

It is the same code I use!!

```
yAxis: [ 
                     { labels: { formatter: function() { return this.value + '".$unitall1."' },  style: { color: '#89A54E'  } },  title: { text: '".$graphall1."' , style: { color : '#4572A7' } },  opposite: true },
                     { labels: { formatter: function() { return this.value + '".$unitall2."' },  style: { color: '#4572A7'  }  }, title: { text: '".$graphall2."' , style: { color : '#89A54E' } },  },  
                     { labels: { formatter: function() { return this.value + '".$unitall3."' },  style: { color: '#000000'  }  }, title: { text: '".$graphall3."' , style: { color : '#000000' } },  },  
                     { labels: { formatter: function() { return this.value + '".$unitall4."' },  style: { color: '#C4087C'  } },  title: { text: '".$graphall4."' , style: { color : '#C4087C' } },  opposite: true }
                       ],
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove space between yAxis and data in highcharts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14331112/remove-space-between-yaxis-and-data-in-highcharts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use offset parameter to set distance yAxis properly.
http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#yAxis.offset

Comment: Isn't this an exact duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

Use the **[`yAxis.offset`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#yAxis.offset)** property to set the offset for each of your y-axis. Looks like the default gap between two axes is lesser in highstock then it is in highchart

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

- use yAxis.offset for each axis, see: http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#yAxis.offset
- use Highstock, but create chart using new Highcharts.Chart() instead of new Highcharts.StockChart(). In that case you can use Highstock features like ordinal axis, range selector, scrollbar etc. You have to just enable each of features directly: http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#scrollbar.enabled